# Product flavor inside flavor in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-productflavors, android-flavors

I can not get product flavours working. I want to achieve flavor inside flavor 
for example, I have 2 applications by which I have declared it like this,

```
 productFlavors {
        abc {
            applicationId = "com.example.abc"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.0.1"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "abc"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon     : "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                    appRoundIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            ]
        }
        def {
            applicationId = "com.example.def"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.0.1"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "def"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon     : "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                    appRoundIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Now I want "def" for development and product by using flavor so how can I achieve this ? Is it possible ?
I want to achieve this,

```
 productFlavors {
    dev {
        flavorDimensions "dev"
    }
    prod {
        flavorDimensions "prod"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move `flavorDimensions` outside try this

```
    flavorDimensions 'product', 'enviroment'
    productFlavors {
        abc {
            applicationId = "com.example.abc"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.0.1"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "abc"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon     : "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                    appRoundIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            ]
            dimension 'product'
        }
        def {
            applicationId = "com.example.def"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.0.1"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "def"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon     : "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
                    appRoundIcon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            ]
            dimension 'product'
        }
        dev {
            dimension 'enviroment'
        }
        prod {
            dimension 'enviroment'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well i have try this code but it gives this error, 
Flavor 'def' has unknown dimension 'product'.

Comment: Really, could you attach full build.gradle file you try

Comment: Sorry i checked again Now its working but dev and prod are same which is "enviroment" in your code i want it to be different like "dev" and "prod" because its urls are different and i have change "dimension" to "flavorDimensions"